# Find name of selected item in matrix and show in a list box by vba

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

i have a matrix (6*6) in sheet1 like below, and Inside its cells, I've written the countifs() formula for the number of correct items, Now i want a Listbox for Returning the name of items from sheet2 
for example: by right-click in the cell (K10) Listbox show the name (USER 1)

sheet2.database;

[image: sheet2.database]

matrix:

[image: matrix]

Comment: You show us (in the attached picture) a matrix of 4x3... Is it just an example, being difficult to create the rest of mentioned elements? So, do you want this (or some other one) to be load in a Listbox? Would be this Listbox a Form or an ActiveX type?

Comment: that's a 6*6 matrix @FaneDuru

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please know this is not a code writing service, so please read the following: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to Create a Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Provide code that you have tried and if/when you run into issues/errors post them too.

Comment: I asked about your Listbox type. How to help you if I do not know for what type of listbox you intend to use? Can I assume that you use am ActiveX type one? Do you know what I mean?

Comment: yes i want ActiveX type one

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an ActiveX listbox on the page keeping the data (your matrix);
2. Access its Properties and set the `ColumnCount` to 6;
3. Set its `ListFilRange` as your 'matrix' address (A2:F7, for instance);
4. Now access its code (View Code in Developer Tab) and select your list box name from the upper left corner;
5. Then select ListBox_Change event from the top left corner;
6. Fill the next code inside it (supposing that your listbox name would be ListBox1):

   `Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
       MsgBox ListBox1.Value
   End Sub`
7. Take care to exit Design Mode (from Developer Tab).

Now, changing the line in the listbox, a message with the first column content, for the selected range will appear...